# Assigning token values isn't working

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

While reading several different ways on creating custom tokens i am still unable to assign values to custom made tokens and i don't understand why.

This is the code for `hook_token_info()`.

```
function my_module_token_info(){
  $info['types']['custom_tokens'] = array(
    'name' => t(Custom Tokens'),
    'description' => t('Custom Tokens'),
  );
  $info['tokens']['custom_tokens']['custom_value_1'] = array(
    'name' => t('Custom Value 1'),
    'description' => t('My custom value 1'),
  );
  $info['tokens']['custom_tokens']['hello_world'] = array(
    'name' => t('Hello World Test'),
    'description' => t('Hello World Test'),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

This is the code for `hook_tokens()`.

```
function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()){
  $replacements = array();
  if($type == 'custom_tokens'){
    foreach($tokens as $name => $original){
      switch($name){
        case 'custom_value_1':
          $replacements[$original] = $data[$name];
          break;
        case 'hello_world':
          $replacements[$original] = 'HELLO WORLD';
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```

This is the code for `hook_webform_submission_presave()`.

```
function my_module_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission){
  token_replace('[custom_tokens:custom_value_1]', array('custom_value_1' => $submission->data[34][0]));
  //this works for some reason
  token_replace('[custom_tokens:hello_world]');
}
```

The token appears in the browse all tokens area. When I run this with xdebug it shows that `token_replace()` does return a string, but when I use this token in webforms email the token is empty. Other tokens that are made with contributed modules are working correctly in the email. If anybody can point out why this isn't working please let me know.

EDIT:
Just to note I am attempting to use the token in an E-mail template in: http://localhost/node/###/webform/emails/8
[current-user] and [submission] tokens are working but these are built by contributed modules.

EDIT:
I tried creating a token that just has static content and doesn't need to use $data. For whatever reason this specific token works in the email template but the tokens with values obtained at run time still don't. I suspect the fact that $submission is a reference variable and it is being altered after the token_replace() might be having some affect although i don't see how.

Comment: You haven't assigned the return value of `token_replace` to anything, so it's being discarded

Comment: would `code`$temp = token_replace()`code` allow the token to retain its info even if $temp isn't being used anywhere in the presave hook?

Comment: token_replace provides you with a new string, you presumably need to do something with that string for it to achieve your goal. Assigning it to a variable you never use won't do that. You need to store it somewhere in the Webform I guess, but only you know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i assumed i could have assigned a value to a token and use it elsewhere. in my case i wanted to assign a custom token a value upon submission and use that token in an email template built in the Drupal UI and not in code.